# Check if a List<Object> contains a property

Tags: java, list, contains

I have the following list in java

```
List<MyObject> =[id ="id", name= "name", time =DateObj, id = "id2", name = "name2".. ]
```

I want to check if this list contains "name2" without having to loop through the list. Is there an API available to achieve this in Java?

Comment: Maybe is good idea, if your create a HashMap with key the name of the object and value MyObject.

Comment: Use Map. Where key would be the field and value you know

Comment: That's not even Java code. I guess `MyObject` contains the fields `id`, `name` and `time`? If so either use a separate map or just iterate over the list elements and check each one.

Answer (score 30):

There is no way to do that without looping. But of course, the loop can be done by a library method instead of being done by you.

The simplest way to do that is to use Java 8 streams:

```
boolean name2Exists = list.stream().anyMatch(item -> "name2".equals(item.getName()));
```

Comment: Damn, streams are so amazing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HashMap<String,MyObject>` in this case.

If you want to check based on the name. Then use name as the key in HashMap.

```
HashMap<String, MyObject> map = new HashMap<String, MyObject>();
map.put(obj.getName(), obj);
```

To check the map contains the particular value.

```
if (map.containsKey("name2")) {
     // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If MyObject is your own class you can override methods equals (and hashcode) appropriately. As a result you could use standard method list.contains

```
List<MyObject> myObjectList = ...;
...
MyObject objectToBeFound = new MyObject("name2", ...);
if (myObjectList.contains(objectToBeFound))
{
    //object is in the list
}
else
{
    //it is not in the list
}
```

PS. But actually there will be anyway some kind of loop which depends on List implementation. Some of them might do plain iteration. :)